# Login to google chrome profile in a docker container

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, python, oauth

I am using [selenium standalone chrome](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome) image to run selenium automation scripts on a docker container. All the websites I am trying to automate have the option to sign in using google. But in order to do that I will need to be logged in to chrome session created by selenium. The brute force way to do that would be to enter my email address and password for my google account and disable 2FA. But I don't want to do that.

I know that we can provide the path to our chrome data directory as options while initializing the webdriver:
`directory_profile = "C:\\User\\yourUserOfYourPc\\AppData\\Local\\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default" #if you have only one profile, you can use this setting, however it's not, type it until "User Data"`

Can I add these credentials to the linux system created by the docker image using google cloud/google api?

Basically I need some way to log in to my google account inside the chrome session created by selenium webdriver in the docker container.

Thank you for your time...

Comment: What do you mean by `using google cloud/google api`? Where are you running your containers and where is your profile stored?

Comment: @jabbson right now my container is running on my windows machine and I'll be deploying it to aws. My profile isn't stored anywhere rn. That's what I need to do. Login to Google and save my origins information at some path in the container. But i dont know how to do that...